# Is there such thing like profiler of building processes?

Tags: linker, compilation, building

I want to narrow down places where can be bottlenecks? Building of my project can take even half an hour. I know many tricks and things which in theory can be guilty, however profiler will be complete solution for all my question.

I am asking about profiler for C++ - GNU GCC - make - Linux - environment, however I am curious if any popular language has such thing.

Answer (score 1):

With gcc you can use the [`-ftime-report`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) option to get the time taken by each compilation stage.